# How to get source for autocomplete jquery mobile from json web service?

Tags: javascript, json, autocomplete

I want to get the data source for autocomplete plugin from my json web service. But I can't put the json string into the data source for autocomplete plugin. but why My data source from my web service didn't show?

here is what shows in my web service json http://www.myservice.com/Service1.svc/list:

```
{"GetReportArResult":[
    {"FNCustomerCode":"RSK346","FnCustomerName":"KITCHEN LANGUAGE PTE LTD"},
    {"FNCustomerCode":"RSL117","FnCustomerName":"LOVELIFE VENTURES PTE LTD"},
    {"FNCustomerCode":"RSU386","FnCustomerName":"UDDERS PTE LTD"},
    {"FNCustomerCode":"RSB638","FnCustomerName":"BODY PLUS PTE LTD"},
    {"FNCustomerCode":"NTU042","FnCustomerName":"NTUC FAIRPRICE (339) -MARSILING MRT"},
    {"FNCustomerCode":"NTU108","FnCustomerName":"NTUC FAIRPRICE (335) -JURONG WEST"},
    {"FNCustomerCode":"RSI559","FnCustomerName":"IGGY'S PTE LTD"},
    {"FNCustomerCode":"RSG843","FnCustomerName":"GOLDEN DEVELOPMENT PTE LTD"},
    {"FNCustomerCode":"RSK583","FnCustomerName":"KOUFU PTE LTD (RASAPURA MASTER)"}
]}
```

this is what I made so far:

```
$("#ar_main").bind("pageshow", function(e) {
    $("#text_customer").autocomplete({
        target: $('#suggestions'),
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "http://www.myservice.com/Service1.svc/list",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term: request.term
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data.GetReportArResult, function(item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.FnCustomerName,
                            value: item.FnCustomerCode
                        };
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        link: 'target.html?term=',
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

Comment: are you fetching data from different domain? it its cross domain request then use `dataType : jsonp`

Comment: @diEcho no, I use `dataType:json` in other function in the same file still works. Is my code right?

Comment: yes, minor syntax error. change the case of `FnCustomerCode` to `FNCustomerCode` ( capital N)  . see [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m5cD4/)  of your json code

Comment: Umm... For starters, the page that you are requesting does not exist. I can't help you with a page that I cannot access.

Comment: @diEcho but if I want the json from my web service, is that code correct? thanks :)